# Get date selection widget in generic form view django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a model task for which I've written the following generic form to give facility to add a new task:

```
class AddTask(generic.CreateView):
    model = task
    fields = ['project','task_name','expected_date']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'st_web/addtask.html'
```

This is working pretty fine. The only problem is that date field is an text type field. I read solutions for similiar questions, one of which proposed writing a date widget in my view like:

```
from django import forms
........................
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
.........................
.........................
class AddTask(generic.CreateView):
    model = task
    fields = ['project','task_name','expected_date']
    widgets = {
        'expected_date': DateInput()
    }
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'st_web/addtask.html'
```

However this doesn't work for me. Can please anyone suggest a simple answer(some of them were suggesting adding some i8j.js or something like that but it'd really be helpful if there is a shorter solution available) to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Normal option is use jQuery DatePicker Plugin and use in template file. and apply to that particular field, very simple and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

In your forms.py :

```
from django import forms

class AddTask(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = task
        fields = ('project','task_name','expected_date', )
        expected_date = forms.DateField(            
        widget = forms.DateInput(
            attrs= {
                    'type':'date',
                    }
        )
        )
```

Comment: I am creating new instance using generic create view, so I need not write the save instance method and all which I will need to write by using forms.ModelForm, no?

Comment: But you can change generic view to `CreareView` and override `def form_valid(self, form):` method.

Comment: Could you please elaborate @Anup Yadav

Comment: Please try the above option with `CreareView` to achieve I believe the answer should work for you. You don't need to oveeride anything like save function, but if you want to then you can manage data processing into `form_valid` method.

Comment: I have my AddTask class in views.py and I placed the suggested answer replacing models.Form with generic.CreateView but still problem did not get solved @AnupYadav